# How to get current mouse location while mouse is being dragged in javascript?

Tags: javascript, mouse-position

In this solution in javascript

[JavaScript while mousedown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15505272/javascript-while-mousedown)

I can get the mouse location when it's first pressed and first clicked, but how can I get the location while its being pressed down?

Thanks

Comment: Use the `mousemove` event?

Comment: what do you mean by location, are you looking for a x, y co-ordinate?

Answer (score 1):

You can track every movement mouse, like this [Track mouse movement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7790725/javascript-track-mouse-position) and add logic for tracking only if before was mouse click down a stop when mouse was click up.

Answer (score 0):

You can get any instance of mouse coordinate inside `<canvas>`. In this case, planting other tags inside `<canvas>` limited and could be done only via `{position: absolute}`.
Code example:

```
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', getPoint);
function getPoint(e){
const [x, y] = [e.offsetX, e.offsetY]; 
const offsetX = document.getElementById('offsetX');
offsetX.textContent = `Offset X: ${x}`;
const offsetY = document.getElementById('offsetY');
offsetY.textContent = `Offset Y: ${y}`;
};
```

Working example: http://codepen.io/462960/pen/RpVJwa