# Execute javascript function every second while the button is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to execute a javascript function continuosly (every second or half a second for example), but this needs to happen while a button is pressed.

I tried with the following:

```
$("#buttonID").bind('touchstart',function(event){ 
        setInterval(function() {
            FUNCTION
        }, 1000);
    });
```

It is not working that way, using "mousedown" either.

What it's answered on question [JavaScript while mousedown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15505272/javascript-while-mousedown)
 did not solve my issue, so I don't consider this question as a duplicate.

Is there a beginner's mistake and I'm not seeing it? what do you suggest?

Comment: Please show what you tried using the mousedown event!

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? Try .on() instead of .bind()

Comment: why are you using bind()? You should be using on() unless you are on an ancient version of jQuery.

Answer (score 5):

You have to capture a reference to the timer and cancel it when the mouse is released.

```js
var timer = null; // Will hold a reference to the timer

$("#buttonID").on('mousedown',function(event){ 
 // Set the timer reference
 timer = setInterval(function() {
   console.log("Function running");
 }, 1000);
});

$("#buttonID").on('mouseup',function(event){ 
 clearInterval(timer);  // Cancel the timer
 console.log("Timer cancelled.");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="buttonID">Hold me down to run function!</button>
```