# keep moving an element up and down while mouse button is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery

Everything works here but I need to keep moving `act` up and down while mouse button is pressed, without repeated clicks.

Any help?

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
 let a = $('.act');
 a.insertBefore(a.prev());
});

$('button').on('contextmenu', function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 let a = $('.act');
 a.insertAfter(a.next());
});
```

```css
.act{background:gold;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<div class='title act'>LOREM</div>
<div class='title'>IPSUM</div>
<div class='title'>DOLOR</div>
<div class='title'>SIT</div>
<div class='title'>AMET</div>
</div>
<br>
<button>CLICK</button>
```

Comment: What does 'while mouse button is pressed' mean? You want an animation to start on mousedown and end on mouseup? Or are you expecting the user to be making repeated clicks?

Comment: @TKoL, no, without repeated clicks, just continue to move while mouse is pressed

Comment: This question should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15505272/javascript-while-mousedown You need to check if the mouse is still down at certain intervals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the `click` and `contextmenu` events you'll have to use mouse events, here is an example:

```js
let intervalId;
const a = $('.act');
$('button').on('mousedown', function(event) {
   function fn () {
    if (event.button == 0) {
      a.insertBefore(a.prev());
    } else if (event.button == 2) {
      a.insertAfter(a.next());
    }
    return fn;
  };
  intervalId = setInterval(fn(), 500);
});

$(document).on('mouseup', function(event) {
  clearInterval(intervalId);
});

$('button').on('contextmenu', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
.act {
  background: gold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class='title act'>LOREM</div>
  <div class='title'>IPSUM</div>
  <div class='title'>DOLOR</div>
  <div class='title'>SIT</div>
  <div class='title'>AMET</div>
</div>
<br>
<button>CLICK</button>
```

In this example, I'm using an interval to move the element every `500` milliseconds while the mouse pointer is down, I'm also preventing the `contextmenu` event so that the context menu will not consume the `mouseup` event itself.

Comment: hmm... common click is lost

Comment: @qadenza What do you mean ?

Comment: click and right click should remain - to move target for just a single place. Plus - if button is continue to be pressed - moving should continue

Comment: @qadenza I've edited the answer to add that functionality.

Comment: there is a conflict with another's elements events. I want to do this if just the button is pressed, and not any other element.

Comment: @qadenza Try to change the selector from `button` to something more specific.

Answer (score 1):

I've made a fiddle to illustrate:

https://jsfiddle.net/10cgxohk/

html:

```
<p class="">x</p>
```

css:

```
.move {
  animation: MoveUpDown 1s linear infinite;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

@keyframes MoveUpDown {
  0%, 100% {
    bottom: 0;
  }
  50% {
    bottom: 15px;
  }
}
```

javascript:

```
$('body').on('mousedown', function() {
    $('p').addClass('move');

  $('body').on('mouseup', function() {
    $('p').removeClass('move');
    $('body').off('mouseup');
    console.log('here');
  })
});
```

This is really rough and creates an issue if you have other 'mouseup' callbacks on the body, but if that's not a worry for you then it should work. The javascript is adding a class to the element, and the class is animated in css

Comment: I think you misunderstood their question. My understanding from their code is that they wish to move the `act` class from each div to the next. If don't think they want a actual animation.

Comment: oh haha well... anyway, my mousedown / mouseup code can be modified if they need to to do that.